# Decision network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

- Do you know what is this, and How they represent decisions (using probabilities) in  Decision Theory

  - Are they similar to decision trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they share similar concepts, and both mainly contains: decision nodes & chance nodes.

Except in a network, you don't necessarily start from one node but it could start with a combination of different nodes, and instead of every node taking **a single input in tree**, in a network, a decision/chance could be based on multiple inputs.

e.g. in a single node in a network : **Weather=Sunny + Holiday=True => go for a hike=True.**
so you dont need to split it into multiple nodes as in trees.

In general, their differences are similar as to **trees** and **graphs** in a traditional sense. You should be able to work out a **decision network** easily if you are familiar with **decision trees**.

Hope this is helpful.